# How to create multiWidget Form

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am creating a pdf from scratch using PDFbox V2, i want to create PDTextField that appear on  different page and have the same value when i fill it.

I already read the example provided by tilman in the doc, but i have specif problem: i'am creating the pdf from json file that contains the informations about the pdf elements , so when i parse the json i don't know yet if the textfield appears on different pages or just on single one.

here is the function that create textField on my pdf.

```
    @Override
    public void writeElement(CustomInputField element, PDDocument document, 
    PDPage page, PDAcroForm acroForm) throws IOException {

    String inputFieldKey = element.getKey();
    PDTextField myTextBox =  (PDTextField) acroForm.getField(inputFieldKey);
    if(myTextBox == null) { // if pdtexField don't exist
        myTextBox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
        myTextBox.setMultiline(true);
        myTextBox.setPartialName(inputFieldKey);
        myTextBox.setAlternateFieldName(element.getTooltip());
        acroForm.getFields().add(myTextBox);
        System.out.println(myTextBox);
    }
    List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();

    PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
    PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(element.getLeft(), page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (element.getTop() + element.getHeight()), element.getWidth(),
            element.getHeight());
    widget.setRectangle(rect);
    widget.setPage(page);
    widget.setParent(myTextBox);
    widget.setPrinted(true);
    page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
    widgets.add(widget);
    myTextBox.setWidgets(widgets);
}
```

Methods call

```
private void writeElementsInPage(PDDocument document, PDPage page, AbstractPDFObject currentElement, PDAcroForm acroForm) throws IOException {

    switch (ElementEnum.resolveElment(currentElement.getClass())) {
    case Rectangle:
        rectangleService.writeElement((CustomRectangle) currentElement, document, page, null);
        break;
    case Image:
        imageService.writeElement((CustomImage) currentElement, document, page, null);
        break;
    case CheckBox:
        checkBoxService.writeElement((CustomInputCheckBox) currentElement, document, page, acroForm);
        break;
    case InputField:
        inputFieldService.writeElement((CustomInputField) currentElement, document, page, acroForm);
        break;
    default:
        System.err.println("UNKNOWN Element\t" + currentElement.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        break;

    }
}
```

the pdf i am getting only have the last occurrence on adobe reader : 
[image]

but on chrome the pdf form appears on all pages :

[image]

this is problem occur on all multi acroform elements that I add on my pdf.

Comment: Can you share the result PDF? And what PDFBox version are you using? Hopefully 2.0.15.

Comment: i am using PDFBox v 2.0.14,  here is the drive link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YJ4ncXOrm9yfJLynu_hzihny-xtXPpLP

Comment: Your acroform has no fields (`Root/AcroForm/Fields` in PDFDebugger). Is the acroform assigned to the document catalog? Or are you using a different acroform object than the one that belongs to the document?

Comment: I accidentally override the Acroform, i think i correct it https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DCNY6p1ZPFplQ7STrOoLZU3kGlh2tTv1, but the main problem is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, it  comes from overriding the list of PDAnnotationWidget, here is how i fix it :

```
@Override
public void writeElement(CustomInputField element, PDDocument document, PDPage page, PDAcroForm acroForm) throws IOException {

    String inputFieldKey = element.getKey();
    PDTextField myTextBox = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField(inputFieldKey);
    List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets;
    if (myTextBox == null) { // if pdtexField don't exist
        myTextBox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
        myTextBox.setMultiline(true);
        myTextBox.setPartialName(inputFieldKey);
        myTextBox.setAlternateFieldName(element.getTooltip());
        acroForm.getFields().add(myTextBox);
        widgets = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        widgets = myTextBox.getWidgets();
    }
    PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
    PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(element.getLeft(), page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (element.getTop() + element.getHeight()), element.getWidth(),
            element.getHeight());
    widget.setRectangle(rect);
    widget.setPage(page);
    widget.setParent(myTextBox);
    widget.setPrinted(true);
    page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
    widgets.add(widget);
    myTextBox.setWidgets(widgets);

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I see it now, the wrong part was that `widgets = new ArrayList<>();` was also hit for the second widget.